# Why unless returning condition when it is false?

Tags: ruby

I have the following ruby code block:

```
x = 1

loop do 
    x+=1

    next unless (x % 2) == 0
    puts x


    break if x >=10
end 

My output:
2
4
6
8
10
```

Here unless is `(x % 2) ==0` which means when it is false, i.e., x% 2 is gives remainder something other than 0, then it should do `puts` but all the multiples of 2's including 2 itself gives `(x%2)==0` as true. Am I misinterpreting unless statement or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `next` statement means to go back to the beginning of the loop.  I think that's what you are missing.

So if `x` is odd, then `(x % 2) == 0` is false, so the `next` statement is executed, which causes the program to skip running the rest of the loop.  This means that odd numbers never get printed.

Answer (score 2):

Your code explicitly says `next unless (x % 2) == 0`, which is the same as `next unless x.even?`, which is the same as `next if x.odd?`, which means "if `x` is odd, go to the next loop iteration". As a result you get the even numbers printed.

Comment: Methods like `odd?` help considerably in communicating your intent. `(x % 2) == 0` is a bit hard to process if you're not paying attention.